# What marks do academics normally get at undergraduate level?

Tags: reference-request, grades

I only know four people who have definite plans for academic careers and I doubt they're a representative sample, so I was wondering what kind of marks people here who are in academia (or plan on having careers in academia) received in their undergraduate degrees.

Note: I'm in the UK where we are awarded percentages that fall under classifications (e.g. 70%+ is a first) - not sure how familiar people outside of the UK are with our system, but this page explains. https://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/content.php?r=15857-degree-classifications I'm not really familiar with systems outside of the UK beyond knowing that a GPA of 4 at university is rare.

Comment: I'm a PhD student who got a 2:1 in undergrad. I asked a few people about this, most academic staff I knew had 1st or 2:1 for their undergrad. I was surprised at the number of academic staff at my old university who had 2:1 from undergrad! Certainly not as many as the ones who had first classes, but it was still more than I expected. /anecdote